# Byte array from Bitmap to BitmapImage in without using class Bitmap C#

Tags: c#, arrays, image, bitmap

I'm doing application where my server running on PC takes a picture from webcam and send it to my Windows Phone 8, where is represented, by using WCF.

Method, which takes a picture from webcam return Bitmap, but Windows Phone doesn't know Bitmap, so I convert Bitmap to byte[] using this (image is Bitmap from webcam):

```
...
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
```

Now I need to make BitmapImage from this received byte[] on the windows phone client side without using class Bitmap. How to do it? Or is there some other solution how to represent this byte[] in XAML `<Image Name="image_video" />`without usint Bitmap and BitmapImage on Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows phone use BitmapImage instead of Bitmap. You can build a BitmapImage object from your byteArray like this:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(yourByteArray))
            {
                BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
                bmpImage.BeginInit();
                bmpImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                bmpImage.EndInit();
                return bmpImage;
            }
```

Comment: Windows Phone 8 BitmapImage hasn't got methods BeginInit, EndInit and StreamSource, so I can't use it...

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Instead of BeginInit, StreamSource and EndInit you use SetSource and it works! Thanks!